# Turning a word into *** symbols

Tags: c, char

So the task is to turn each word in the sentence starting with uppercase into "***".

`

```
for (i = 1; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if(isupper(input[i]))   input[i] = '***';

printf("\n Changed sentence is:     %s", input);
```

`

This is a code I've written so far. It can change only one character but I don't know how to do it with he whole word.

Comment: What is input??

Comment: Are you supposed to replace the word with exactly three asterisks, or is each _character_ in that word supposed to be replaced with _one_ asterisk?

Comment: Please, define what is a _word_ for you.  As you program does, it is any uppercase letter in a string.  If you think the same, your definition of a word and mine differ too much.  Edit your question and say what is for you a _word_.  Also, please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a potential solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[] = "The Mississippi river is very Wide.";

    printf("%s\n", input);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
        if((i != 0) && isupper(input[i]))
        {
            printf("*** ");
            while(input[i] != ' ')
                i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", input[i]);
        }
    }

    if(ispunct(input[strlen(input) - 1]))
        printf("\b%c\n", input[strlen(input) - 1]);
    else
        printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe
The Mississippi river is very Wide.
The *** river is very ***.
```

Comment: Great! It seems to me that to change into "***" we need to change the number of characters of the initial word.

Comment: Are you saying that regardless of the length of the word only three asterisks should be printed?

Comment: Yes, there should be only 3 of them.

Comment: Almost there. First word should not be changed.

Comment: Thanks you a lot!

Comment: Wait, if the word woth uppercase is last, then punct (. or ! or ?) go into "***". What should I change?

Answer (score 2):

I assume `input` is a properly allocated, null terminated C string.

---

You scan (within the loop) one character at a time; similarly you can change one character at a time.

So you need an additional variable where you store if the word parsed should be converted to a sequence of asterisks.

As you encounter a uppercase letter at the beginning of a word the variable is set to true.

As you encounter the end of the current word (a whitespace) you reset the variable to false.

Finally you change (or not) the current character accordingly.

See the comments in the code

```
// you need a variable to record if the current word
// should be converted to a sequence of '*'
bool toAsterisk = false;

// sentence scanning loop (one character at a time)
// note that index starts at 0 (not 1)
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    // check if the current word should be converted to asterisks
    if( isupper( input[i] ) && toAsterisk == false )
    {
        toAsterisk = true;
    }

    // check if you rwach the end of the current word
    if( input[i] == ' ' )
    {
        toAsterisk = true;
    }

    // convert to asterisks?
    if( toAsterisk )
    {
        input[ i ] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to change the whole word into 3 asterisks?

Answer (score 1):

Read through the line. 
If character is capitalized, enter while loop until you get a space or end of line and replacing characters with *.

Print the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  char line[1024] = "This should Replace capitalized Words!";
  int i = 0;

  printf("line: %s\n", line);

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
    if (isupper(line[i])) {
      while (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\0' && isalpha(line[i])) {
        line[i] = '*';
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("line: %s\n", line);
  return 0;
}
```

**Outputs**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror test.c -o t
line: This should Replace capitalized Words!
line: **** should ******* capitalized *****!
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, following the feedback seen in the comments, here is my version that doesn't depend on the input line length or memory available to the program.  It implements a finite state automaton, three states, to detect first letter, next letters and nonword letters.  Following a possible implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define IDLE    (0)
#define FIRST   (1)
#define NEXT    (2)

int main()
{
    int status = IDLE;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isupper(c)) {
            switch (status) {
            case IDLE:
                status = FIRST;
                printf("***");
                break;
            case FIRST: case NEXT:
                status = NEXT;
                break;
            } /* switch */
        } else if (islower(c)) {
            switch (status) {
            case IDLE:
                putchar(c);
                break;
            case FIRST: case NEXT:
                status = NEXT;
            } /* switch */
        } else {
            switch (status) {
            case IDLE:
                putchar(c);
                break;
            case FIRST: case NEXT:
                putchar(c);
                status = IDLE;
                break;
            } /* switch */
        } /* if */
    } /* while */
} /* main */
```

Answer (score -1):

By changing one character to three (you change them to three stars) you change length of string. Try starting from there. [This issue may affect the way loop should work]

Comment: Well, It changes only into 1 character.

Comment: In the second line you have: "input[i] = '***';"

Comment: I mean that on practics it turns only into 1 charecter. But question is not going about this.